# Getting an order item unit price, after any discount has been applied in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to get the unit price of an item from an order that has had a discount applied to it?

For example order number #12345 contains 4 products each with a normal unit price of £3.00. A discount is applied which takes off 25% each item.

How can I then access that cost from each order from `$order->getAllItems()` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
  $productid = $item->getProductId();     
  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
}
```

from this way you can get ordered item unit price.

Comment: This won't include any discount deductions though, which is what I'm looking for.